# Typing my app name into the Facebook search bar triggers FBRPC error

Tags: facebook, macos, facebook-graph-api, safari

Okay, I'm at my wits end - I can't figure this one out.  If you go into Facebook in Safari on a desktop/laptop and in the search bar type the name of my app: "Hopple Hop", and then click on the app itself (not the app page), instead of launching the app, it triggers this error message in Safari:

"Safari can't open "fbrpc://nativethirdparty/f?appid="

Followed by hundreds of characters.  Basically, it's a big long URL string, in the "fbrpc://" protocol, and it tries to launch directly into the browser as-is.

As you can imagine, this is not the intended functionality of searching for my app.  The intended functionality is that they type "Hopple Hop", click on it, and the Facebook canvas game starts.  If you go to

https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/hopplehop/

You can see it there.  And if you click "Play Now", it launches properly from:

https://apps.facebook.com/hopplehop/

I know it's probably a configuration issue.  There is also an iOS app to go with it.

Comment: Is this safari on iOS?

Comment: I just tried it. Worked for me

Comment: Sorry no - this is Safari on a laptop.  The expected functionality is that when searching for "Hopple Hop" on a desktop/laptop it will launch the FB canvas app. It's strange, because it seems to work from the App Center search, but literally not on my FB home page search...

Comment: Just tried it on Safari on Mavericks - worked for me.

Comment: I only get one search result.  URIs with fbrpc:// are only valid on the mobile device - is it perhaps something with your configuration that is giving you fbrpc:// uris on your desktop?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.. the thing is, I can't find anything that would specify that this should happen.  I've got an iOS and a Desktop app associated with the app, but they are very clearly separate items. I'm thinking this might be a FB configuration thing that I'll need to reach out to them about?

Comment: Maybe.  It may also occur because you have installed both apps, whereas I haven't.  Have you tried from another FB login?

Comment: Very interesting.  So I just tried it on my wife's login, and much to my surprise, it worked. So I was making the assumption that it was broken, globally, while it seems to be something specific to me. It's odd behaviour, but at least it seems to be only affecting me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the end cause was, to be honest.  It appears to be a very specific configuration issue with my phone / Facebook account and the way I've authorized the game.  It doesn't seem to be an issue for anyone else.  I don't unfortunately know the root cause.

But if anyone else sees this error, it's likely only you are seeing it.

Thanks,
Glen